# Why does the `sqrt()` print the desired output when I use `float`s instead of `double`s?

Tags: c, sqrt

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double hypotenuse( double side1, double side2 );

int main( void )
{
    double a, b;

    printf( "Enter the values of the two sides: " );
    scanf( "%f %f", &a, &b );
    printf( "\nThe length of hypotenuse is: %f", hypotenuse( a, b ) );   

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

double hypotenuse( double side1, double side2 )
{
       double c;

       c = (side1 * side1) + (side2 * side2);
       return sqrt( c );
}
```

The above program works when I use `float a, b;` instead of `double a,b;`. Why?

Comment: Any issues remaining for this post?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your code, you use

```
scanf( "%f %f", &a, &b );
```

But `%f` is used for a `float` ,not a `double`. Try `%lf` for a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

For `scanf()`, the specifier `"%f"` expects a `float *` argument, not a `double *`.

```
double a;
//           v--- &a is type double *, scanf("%f" expects float *
scanf( "%f", &a );
```

To scan in `double`, use specifier `"%lf"` which expects a `double *` argument.

```
double a;
//            v--- &a is type double *
scanf( "%lf", &a );
```

Detail: The arguments to `scanf()` are *addresses* of where `scanf()` can store the results.  A `float *` is not the same as `double *`.

With `printf()`, numeric arguments are the *value* to print.   Since `printf()` takes variable number of arguments, they go through *usual* promotions like `float` to `double`.  Thus `printf("%f", some_float)` and `printf("%f", some_double)` can use the same format specifier.  *Usual* promotions does not apply to `&a`, `&b` with `scanf()` as those argument are pointers (addresses), not arithmetic values.

---

Note: Always good to check `scanf()` results.  The space between `"%lf"` and `"%lf"` is not needed as `"%lf"` itself consumes leading white-space, yet it is often visually easier to understand.

```
if (2 != scanf( "%lf%lf", &a, &b )) Handle_Error();
```